# Call class function in BroadcastReceiver onReceive function

Tags: java, android

I have a service with a `BroadcastReceiver`.
How can I call a function in the service class from the `onReceive` function of the `BroadcastReceiver`?
And if I can't, what can I do?
Here is some code :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                ... // How to call myFunction() here?
            }
        };
        ... // intentFilter, registerReceiver, etc...
    }

    private void myFunction() {
        ... // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it like this:

```
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            myFunction();
        }
    };
```

Or, if `myFunction` has the same name as a `BroadcastReceiver` method, you can explicitly call the outer class method like this:

```
    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            MyService.this.myFunction();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I write the wrong function name so the IDE didn't find the function and I thought that their was something special to do. Thank you